# Dynamically Adding a GroupBy to a Lambda Expression

Tags: linq, expression-trees

Ok, I'll admit that I don't entirely "get" lambda expressions and LINQ expression trees yet; a lot of what I'm doing is cutting and pasting and seeing what works. I've looked over lots of documentation, but I still haven't found the my "aha" moment yet.

With that being said...

I'm attempting to dynamically add a GroupBy expression to my Linq expression. I followed the question here:
[Need help creating Linq.Expression to Enumerable.GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650346/need-help-creating-linq-expression-to-enumerable-groupby)

and tried to implement what I saw there.

First off, I've got entity classes for my database, and a table calledObjCurLocViewNormalized

I've got an method that does the initial call,

```
public IQueryable<ObjCurLocViewNormalized> getLocations()
{
    IQueryable<ObjCurLocViewNormalized> res = (from loc in tms.ObjCurLocViewNormalized
                               select loc);
    return res;
}
```

so I can call:

```
IQueryable<MetAmericanLinqDataModel.ObjCurLocViewNormalized> locations = american.getLocations();
```

No problem so far.

Now, I want to group by an arbitrary column, with a call like this:

```
var grouped = locations.addGroupBy(childLocationFieldName);
```

Right now, I have a method :

```
static public System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string, TResult>> addGroupBy<TResult>(this IQueryable<TResult> query, string columnName)
{

    var providerType = query.Provider.GetType();
    // Find the specific type parameter (the T in IQueryable<T>)
    var iqueryableT = providerType.FindInterfaces((ty, obj) => ty.IsGenericType && ty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>), null).FirstOrDefault();
    var tableType = iqueryableT.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var tableName = tableType.Name;

    var data = Expression.Parameter(iqueryableT, "query");
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(tableType, tableName);
    var nameProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, columnName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, string>>(nameProperty, arg);

    var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), 
                                    "GroupBy", 
                                    new Type[] { tableType, typeof(string) },
                                    data, 
                                    lambda);
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, String>>(expression, arg); // this is the line that produces the error I describe below
    var result = query.GroupBy(predicate).AsQueryable();
    return result;
}
```

All this compiles ok, but when I run it, I get the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,MetAmericanLinqDataModel.ObjCurLocViewNormalized]]' cannot be used for return type 'System.String'
```

and the error comes from this line:

```
 var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, String>>(expression, arg);
```

I'm copying and adapting this code from successful work I did in dynamically added Where clauses to an expression. So I'm sort of stabbing in the dark here.

If anyone out there can help to shed some light on this, Obviously posting complete working code and doing all my thinking for me would be great :), but if you could just lay out just why this is wrong, or how to wrap my head around these concepts, that would be great. If you can point to documentation that can really help be bridge the gap between the basics of lambda expressions, and building dynamic expression trees, that would be great. There's obviously big holes in my knowledge, but I think this information could be useful to others.

thanks everyone for your time, and of course if I find the answer elsewhere, I'll post it here.

Thanks again.

Don

Comment: Why is your `predicate` line using `Func<TResult, string>`?  Your experssion returns an `IGrouping` which is not a `string`.

Comment: thanks kirk, I tried: changing the line to : var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, IGrouping<String, TResult>>>(expression, arg); but now I get the compilation error: Error 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,TResult>,TResult>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,TResult>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) . Is that the incorrect way to write what you're telling me?

Comment: the main problem is you're confusing the invocation of `.GroupBy` with the lambda predicate that you pass to *it*.  Don't have time to answer further at the moment, but if this question is still unanswered an hour from now, I'll take a more thorough stab.

Comment: ah, and that error has to do with a mismatch with the return type. But I don't think I want to change the return type, do i?

Answer (score 2):

The solution should be pretty simple:

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<TColumn, T>> DynamicGroupBy<T, TColumn>(
    IQueryable<T> source, string column)
{
    PropertyInfo columnProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty(column);
    var sourceParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var propertyReference = Expression.Property(sourceParm, columnProperty);
    var groupBySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TColumn>>(propertyReference, sourceParm);

    return source.GroupBy(groupBySelector);
}
```

Assuming a sample class like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

You invoke it like this:

```
var list = new List<TestClass>();
var queryable = list.AsQueryable();
DynamicGroupBy<TestClass, string>(queryable, "TestProperty");
```

Comment: Seems that your answer is similar to mine, but now so full and with code refactoring =)

Comment: Hm, looks promising, but "No overload for method 'Parameter' takes '1' arguments." So it's doesn't like the line: var sourceParm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
I'm on 3.5. is this a .Net 4.0 thing? I am upgrading soon.

Comment: @donundeen, yes that's a .Net 4 thing, but it hardly matters. Just pass as the second parameter any string you feel helps identify the parameter, or just "x". It doesn't matter. :)

Answer (score 0):

All that you need to do to make it work is the following:

```
    static public IQueryable<IGrouping<TValue, TResult>> addGroupBy<TValue, TResult>(
                this IQueryable<TResult> query, string columnName)
            {
            var providerType = query.Provider.GetType();

            // Find the specific type parameter (the T in IQueryable<T>)
            const object EmptyfilterCriteria = null;
            var iqueryableT = providerType
                .FindInterfaces((ty, obj) => ty.IsGenericType && ty.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>), EmptyfilterCriteria)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            Type tableType = iqueryableT.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            string tableName = tableType.Name;

            ParameterExpression data = Expression.Parameter(iqueryableT, "query");
            ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(tableType, tableName);
            MemberExpression nameProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, columnName);
            Expression<Func<TResult, TValue>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, TValue>>(nameProperty, arg);
            //here you already have delegate in the form of "TResult => TResult.columnName"
            return query.GroupBy(lambda);

        /*var expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), 
                                        "GroupBy", 
                                        new Type[] { tableType, typeof(string) },
                                        data, 
                                        lambda);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TResult, String>>(expression, arg); // this is the line that produces the error I describe below
        var result = query.GroupBy(predicate).AsQueryable();
        return result;*/
    }
```

And you will call you expression in the following manner:

```
var grouped = locations.addGroupBy<string, ObjCurLocViewNormalized>(childLocationFieldName);
```

First generic parameter "string" us used for saying explicilty what type of elements you a grouping on. For example you can group by "int" field and method call will be like following:

```
var grouped = locations.addGroupBy<int, ObjCurLocViewNormalized>(someFieldNameWithTheTypeOfInt);
```

**Edit**
Just to finish this solution *your way*:

```
 //return query.GroupBy(lambda);
    MethodCallExpression expression = Expression.Call(typeof (Enumerable),
                                                      "GroupBy",
                                                      new[] { typeof(TResult), typeof(TValue) },
                                                      data,
                                                      lambda);

    var result = Expression.Lambda(expression, data).Compile().DynamicInvoke(query);
    return ((IEnumerable<IGrouping<TValue, TResult>>)result).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: why do you have that funky code after the comment `// Find the specific type parameter (the T in IQueryable<T>)`?  Surly you already have that information in `TResult`, no?

Comment: I prefer do not touch original code, cos question was about other thing. Sure code can be improved.